# Неправильно добавляются переводы строк

Tags: php

Я хочу, чтобы после `[list]` не ставился `\n`, а начинался `[*]` и после `[/list]` не ставился `\n`, ну или `<br>`, а то получается, что лишние строчки пропускаются.

Но мне надо например, что если я пишу без `bbcode`, то всё нормально отображалось, то есть, как написал, так и выглядит.

> Как дела?
>   Нормально.

И в общем у меня есть такая функция:

```
function parse_content ( $s ) {
    $res = str_replace ( "<", "&lt;", $s );
    $res = str_replace ( ">", "&gt;", $res );
    $res = str_replace("\\r", "&#92;&#114;", $res);
    $res = str_replace("\\t", "&#92;&#116;", $res);
    $res = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $res );
    $res = preg_replace( "/\[(code)=([a-z+]*)\][\n]?/i", "<pre><code class=\"$2\" id=\"code\">", $    res );
    $res = str_replace("\\n", "&#92;&#110;", $res);
    $res = str_replace ( "[/code]", "</code></pre>", $res );
    $res = preg_replace ( "/\[([a-z]|[\*]{1})*\][\n]/i", "[$1]", $res );
    $res = preg_replace ( "/\[\/([a-z]|[\*]{1})*\][\n]/i", "[/$1]", $res );
    $res = str_replace ( "\n", "<br>", $res );
    $bbcode = new ChrisKonnertz\BBCode\BBCode();
    $rendered = $bbcode->render ( $res );
    return $rendered;
}
```

Я в textarea пишу такой текст.

```
Привет. Как дела?
Нормально.
[list]
[*] helo
[*] priv
[/list]
это код.
[code=c++]
#include <stdio.h>
[/code]
end
```

Comment: я хотел после или написать br в тегах, а он выполнил это как те страницы.

Comment: О боге. Ужасно. Массивы? не не слышал.

Comment: @xverizex Дайте пример входящих данных.

Comment: @Denis640Kb добавил входные данные.